# F1 2016 - Loading setups from Steam Workshop

Tags: steam, steam-workshop

I'm playing F1 2016 on Steam, and joined a couple of online races; I noticed that at the start of every race I can edit the car setup and there is also the button to open the Steam Workshop and load setups from there, but it's always empty: why?

Do I have to subscribe to the setups from the Steam client in order to have them listed on the game?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the [Steam Workshop](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/) works is similar to how you described.
Yes, you have to *subscribe* to the Wokrshop Item you want to load in to (perhaps *) use it.

And you probably know, but to reassure you, you don't pay anything when subscribing to any item on the Workshop.

(*: If the item is broken or incomplete, errors may occur, hence why I put the * there to tell you.)